# Angular 5.2 Error: Cannot convert type 'Observable<something[]> to type 'Observable<somethingElse>'

Tags: angular, typescript

Using Angular 5.2, I'm getting this resharper typescript error:
Cannot convert type 'Observable<IPartBundle[]> to type 'Observable<IOrderHead>'

```
public orderHead$: Observable<IOrderHead>;

ngOnInit() {

    this.orderHead$ = this.route.paramMap.switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
        this.partBundle$ = this.orderShipService.getPartBundleObservable(this.orderShipDetails$, this.cartons$, this.licensePlate, this.orderLine);
        return this.order.getOrderHeadObservable(+params.get('orderNumber'));
    }).share();
}
```

Comment: no idea what's wrong... without data and minimal reproducible and complete example can't help ya. [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Resharper wants the type included in the share method, like this.

```
this.orderHead$ = this.route.paramMap.switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
    this.partBundle$ = 
this.orderShipService.getPartBundleObservable(this.orderShipDetails$, 
this.cartons$, this.licensePlate, this.orderLine);
    return this.order.getOrderHeadObservable(+params.get('orderNumber'));
}).share<IOrderHead>();
```

Then, the resharper error goes away.